# How to add spaces to any given string and maintain N chars?

Tags: regex, ruby, string

In Ruby using regex, I want to modify a given string that will be shorter than or exactly 15 characters, so that it is always 15 characters by adding spaces.

For example:

```
'apple' => 'apple(10 spaces here)'

'orange' => 'orange(9 spaces here)'

'fifteenspaceshi' => 'fifteenspaceshi'
```

I have tried this and it works but would regex have a more elegant solution?

```
x = 'apple'

x = x + ' '*(15 - x.length)
```

Comment: Regex are generally slower and result in less readable code and can easily hide logic errors that bite you at 3AM. Sure, they're cool but senior developers learn to use them carefully, usually because of those 3AM panic sessions.

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful you should select the one you found most helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to involve regex

```
"apple".ljust(15) # => "apple          "
```

Comment: btw, `ljust` receives placeholder as well, e.g. `"apple".ljust(15, '_')`

Answer (score 4):

I think Sergio's answer is the best based on the complexity of the question, but you can also use string formatting (`sprintf`) if you need more complex formatting later:

```
"%-15s" % "apple" # => "apple          "
```

Read [documentation](https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/49-what-the-format.html) for the patterns and how to read/write them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using a left padding trick:

```
padding = "               "
input = "123" + padding
puts input.chars.first(15).join

"123            "
        ^^ 12 spaces
```

The idea here is to concatenate a string containing 15 spaces to the *right* of the input string.  Then, we retain the first 15 characters of that concatenated result.

Comment: Or `input[0...15]` instead of `input.chars.first(15).join`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm a newcomer to the wide world of Ruby.  Actually, I am short my daily quota for points, so I'm trolling around everywhere now :P

Comment: You might want to drop the use of trailing semicolons as they're rarely necessary and often contribute to code that's hard to read, and we know what happens when unnecessary stuff joins with hard to read stuff....